# Make checbox/checkboxGroup(All Option) required in visual Flow

Tags: salesforce1-app, process-builder, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I am building a form which in the end is having some declaration which needs to be checked by the user in order to go to the next screen. Unable to get the same using checkbox and have used checkbox group however even in checkbox group selection of one is mandatory.

Is there any way to have all needs to be checked to move to the next screen As group is having only one marked as required condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make chcekbox as required which is not a option as default in salesforce. I have used the validation part with the formula as

IF({!checkoxAPIName}=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)

and correspondingly showed the error message